# Starting jetty service from SSH

Tags: ssh, service, daemon, jetty

I am trying to start jetty service from ssh using the command:

> ssh -t myhost  "sudo /sbin/service jetty6 start"

All works well, service comes up but after the command terminates and the connection closes down, the Jetty service goes down, too. If I log into ssh and do the "service" command manually, all works fine.

I have tried to use the recipe from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/36419/using-ssh-to-remotely-start-a-process/36436#36436), that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Before:

```
# service jetty status
 * Jetty servlet engine is not running.
```

Use(localhost:2022 virtual machine hostname):

```
$ ssh -p 2022 localhost "sudo service jetty start"
 * Starting Jetty servlet engine. jetty
 * Jetty servlet engine started, reachable on http://u1004s01:8080/. jetty
   ...done.
$
```

Result:

```
# service jetty status
 * Jetty servlet engine is running with pid 2623, and is reachable on http://:8080/
```

Command service not need go to the background.
Add output command:

```
ssh myhost "sudo /sbin/service jetty6 start;sleep 60;sudo /sbin/service jetty6 status;ps aux | grep jetty"
```

Comment: Yeah, `sleep` is one of the things I tried (no pun intended). The daemon is up as long as the connection to the host is open. When the ssh command exits, the daemon goes down. Strange, I know :-)

Please note that I have to do "ssh -t myhost 'sudo ...'" as without -t sudo won't work, says "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Answer (score 1):

You try backgrounding the process?  Maybe SSH is terminating before the init script finishes. `ssh -t myhost "sudo /sbin/service jetty6 start &"`

Or, try with `nohup`, too?

Comment: I really hate these "community" bumps on old questions... -_-